# Can't return result in Unity Activity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, startactivityforresult

I got the following Problem,

I have an App which hosts my `UnityApplication` which is called from my `MainApplication` via `startActivityForResult`.
I set the `Result` before calling **mUnityPlayer.quit**, but when returning to the main app the data intent is always null.

Code in the onDestroy Part:

```
 @Override protected void onDestroy ()
    {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"UnityApp.onDestroy called");
        closeSession();
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"UnityApp.onDestroy: after closeSession");
        //finish();
        setResult(resultCode,resultData);
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"UnityApp.onDestroy: Result set 1");
        UnityPlayer.currentActivity.setResult(resultCode,resultData);
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"UnityApp.onDestroy: Result set 2");
        this.mUnityPlayer.quit();
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"UnityApp.onDestroy: after super.onDestroy");
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"UnityApp.onDestroy: after mUnityPlayer.quite");
        UnityPlayer.currentActivity.finish();
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"UnityApp.onDestroy after finish");
   }
```

Code of Calling Activity:

```
@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == CALL_EXTERN_APP) {
                Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "ListFiles:");
                txtHelloWorld.setText("data==null");
                if(data==null) return;
                txtHelloWorld.setText("no Filename");
                if(!data.hasExtra(EXTRA_SESSION_FILENAME)) return;
                txtHelloWorld.setText("no Filecontent");
                if(!data.hasExtra(EXTRA_SESSION_FILECONTENT))return;
                txtHelloWorld.setText("Successful");
                if (resultCode == 0 && callSuccess) {
                    String filename = data.getStringExtra(EXTRA_SESSION_FILENAME);
                    String[] filecontent = data.getStringArrayExtra(EXTRA_SESSION_FILECONTENT);
                    File file = new File(getFilesDir(),filename);
                        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "onActivityResult:" + filecontent.length + " Lines to write to " + filename);
                        try {
                            if(!file.exists())
                            file.createNewFile();
                            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            for (int l = 0; l < filecontent.length; l++) {
                                fout.write(filecontent[l].getBytes());
                                Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "onActivityResult:" + "Line " + (l + 1) + ": " + filecontent[l]);
                            }
                            fout.close();
                            Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "onActivityResult: Write to " + filename + " done");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there any better solution to return Data from Extern Unity App to my Main App?

Comment: Its not a good idea to execute this code `onDestroy()`. Can you try to move the codes in `onDestory()` to the place where this activity finishes its task?

Comment: Which part of the code do you mean?

Comment: You must be calling `finish()` somewhere because of which `onDestroy()` is called. You can execute the code before executing `onFinish()`

Comment: Thanks that was it

Comment: Great! I will update it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a great idea to execute this code in onDestroy(). You should move the code to the place where you are calling `finish()`. This would ensure that your code works reliably and ensure `onActivityResult()` is called appropriately.